# how to use Gmail smtp in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, smtp

I am new to Xcode I need an app to send a email. Background: the destination email Id is typed in a text and by clicking the send button the message body *Sample* should go to the destination Email ID I tried this code in the function button clicked but it is not working when ever i try this code I get error in function can any one guide me with a step by step tutorial

mailTransfer[673:207] delegate - error(-5): timeout sending message
                2014-07-05 10:54:05.393 mailTransfer[673:207] *** stopping watchdog *** I had added the SMTP files from google documents ... any other way to correct this code

```
     - (IBAction)sendMessageInBack:(id)anObject
    {   

                        SKPSMTPMessage *testMsg = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
                        testMsg.fromEmail = @"Yours mail ids";
                        testMsg.toEmail = emailField.text;
                        testMsg.relayHost = @"smtp.gmail.com";
                        testMsg.requiresAuth = YES;
                        testMsg.login = @"Your mail ids";
                        testMsg.pass = @"id password";
                        testMsg.subject = @"Test application ";
                        testMsg.wantsSecure = YES; 
                        testMsg.delegate = self;
                        NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionarydictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,@"Sample",kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];
                        testMsg.parts = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,nil];
                        [testMsg send];
    }
    -(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message{
        [message release];
        NSLog(@"delegate - message sent");
    }
    -(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error{
        [message release];
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Error" message:@"Unable to send email" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alert show];
        [alert release];
        NSLog(@"delegate - error(%d): %@", [error code], [error localizedDescription]);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in SKPSMTPMessage.m

update the following line

```
CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions,kCFStreamSSLLevel,kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
```

with

```
CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3);
```

Answer (score 0):

Download SMTP framework and import SKPSMTPMessage class..

```
#import "SKPSMTPMessage.h"
-(void)sendEmailVideo:(NSString*)_toEmailAddress andCC:(NSString*)ccEmail

{
@try
    {

    // Message =[data getContentOfPanic];

    NSData *webData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:videoURL];
    SKPSMTPMessage *emailMessage = [[SKPSMTPMessage alloc] init];
    emailMessage.fromEmail=@"nikki.varsha@gmail.com";//sender email address

    emailMessage.toEmail=_toEmailAddress;
    //receiver email address
    emailMessage.relayHost=@"smtp.gmail.com";
    //emailMessage.ccEmail =ccEmail;
    emailMessage.requiresAuth = YES;
    emailMessage.login = @"nikki.varsha@gmail.com"; //sender email address
    emailMessage.pass = @"123";
    //sender email password
    emailMessage.subject =@"Panic Video Message";
    emailMessage.wantsSecure = YES;
    emailMessage.delegate = self;
    NSDictionary *plainPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/plain",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                               Message,kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"8bit",  kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];


    NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"Video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                             @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"Video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[webData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

    emailMessage.parts=[NSArray arrayWithObjects:plainPart,vcfPart,nil];
    dispatch_queue_t backgroundVideoQueue = dispatch_queue_create("com.VideoQue", 0);

    dispatch_sync(backgroundVideoQueue, ^{
        [emailMessage send];
    });
}
@catch (NSException *exception)
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Host" message:@"No Reciever Email Ids Available! " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
}
```

## pragma mark - sendEmail delegate (SKPSMTPMessage)

-(void)messageSent:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message

{

```
NSLog(@"delegate - Email sent");
NSLog(@"Mesg %@",message);
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Email sent." message:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Ok" otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
```

}

-(void)messageFailed:(SKPSMTPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error

{

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
NSLog(@"err=%@" ,message);
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]
                      initWithTitle:@"Error"
                      message:@"Unable to send email Please Check EmailId & Password"
                      delegate:self
                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                      otherButtonTitles: nil];
[alert show];
});
```

}

Comment: I tried your code but now i get a alert like this NO hosts No reciver IDS avilable

Comment: I tried this code but it is not working its executing the exception

Comment: here i m sending video file so file name is video.mov .

Comment: Sometimes gmail doesn't work so try any microsoft account or any other emailMessage.relayHost=@"smtp.gmail.com";                              replace                                                                                                                                                                                emailMessage.relayHost=@"smtp.live.com";

Comment: can you send that demo in a .zip file to aj.sabeen@gmail.com

Comment: Now the code works in ios stimulator 4.3 but My project is based on stimulator 5.0 so what are the modification i should perform

Comment: how have to alter any coading , settings

Comment: Remove this and run                                                        NSDictionary *vcfPart = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:@"text/directory;\r\n\tx-unix-mode=0644;\r\n\tname=\"Video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentTypeKey,
                             @"attachment;\r\n\tfilename=\"Video.mov\"",kSKPSMTPPartContentDispositionKey,[webData encodeBase64ForData],kSKPSMTPPartMessageKey,@"base64",kSKPSMTPPartContentTransferEncodingKey,nil];

Comment: tis code runs on ios stimulator 4.3 for 5.0 stimulator not working
stimulator not xcode

Comment: You are doing something wrong..because i didn't face this type of problem.

Comment: can you give me the tutorial link

Comment: have you checked github links

Comment: https://github.com/jetseven/skpsmtpmessage                    https://github.com/kailoa/iphone-smtp                     https://github.com/eax/skpsmtpmessage

Comment: in this i get a message OS status error in ios 5.0 stimulator

Comment: in SKPSMTPMessage.m
change
//CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1); 
CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3); 
IT works .....  Thank u

Answer (score -1):

in SKPSMTPMessage.m file do change the following line

Remove this line

```
//CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions,kCFStreamSSLLevel,kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelTLSv1);
```

Add this line

```
CFDictionarySetValue(sslOptions, kCFStreamSSLLevel, kCFStreamSocketSecurityLevelSSLv3);
```

Thanks